# Why successive vector::push_back results into different number of constructor call?

Tags: c++, vector, destructor, copy-constructor

```
class base
{
    private:
            int k;
    public:
            base(const base& b){ this->k = b.k; cout<<"  c-ctor "<<endl; }
            base(int a = 10){ k = a; }

            ~base(){cout << "destructor called\n";}
};

int main()
{
    base b, b1(2);
    vector<base> m;
    cout << "first pushback" <<endl;
    m.push_back(b);
    cout << "2nd pushback" <<endl;
    m.push_back(b1);
    cout << "3rd pushback" <<endl;
    m.push_back(b1);
    cout << "4th pushback" <<endl;
    m.push_back(b);
    cout << "5th pushback" <<endl;
    m.push_back(b);
    cout<<" =============================================== "<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
first pushback
  c-ctor 
2nd pushback
  c-ctor 
  c-ctor 
destructor called
3rd pushback
  c-ctor 
  c-ctor 
  c-ctor 
destructor called
destructor called
4th pushback
  c-ctor    
5th pushback
  c-ctor 
  c-ctor 
  c-ctor 
  c-ctor 
  c-ctor 
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
 =============================================== 

destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
```

Why **i<sup>th</sup>** `push_back` leading to **i** number of copy constructor calls?

Isn't it a **resizing effect**( i.e. copying the original vector again) and rather inefficient way of inserting elements into a vector?

Why **4<sup>th</sup>** `push_back` is having different behavior than **2<sup>th</sup>**, **3<sup>th</sup>** abd **5<sup>th</sup>** `push_back`?

[Demo](http://ideone.com/rx4Pgv)

Comment: What do you think happens when the vector is of size x and you add the xth+1 item?

Comment: Adding a value to the output might help (sometimes): `cout<<"  c-ctor "<< k << endl`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a big deal. vectors are reallocated everytime its `size` reaches its `capacity`. All the elements are copied from old vector to new vector.

Generally, twice the original capacity is allocated for new vector.

1. Before 1st `push_back`, capacity is 1. So it does not need to be re-allocated.
2. For 2nd `push_back`, capacity needs to double, so two calls to copy constructor are made, first to copy old element to new vector and second for `push_back`. Capacity is now 2.
3. Third `push_back` again needs to reallocate the vector because capacity is now 2. After reallocation capacity becomes 4.
4. Now no reallocation happens, so just one call to copy ctor (for `push_back`). Capacity is still 4.
5. For 5th `push_back`, reallocation happens and 4 old elements and one new element (`push_back`) are copied to the new vector. Capacity is now 8.

If you go ahead further, you'll observe that reallocation will happen on 9th `push_back`.

Also, destructors need to be called while reallocation, when the older vector is no longer needed and hence the members in it should be destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) could be seen as a *dynamic array*. As such it grows when there is a need and this requires the vector to allocate more memory and ***copy*** the existing elements in the vector to the new larger memory.

The existing objects in the old memory are then destructed.

If you know beforehand how many elements you need in the vector you can [*reserve*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) memory for the vector. By doing this the vector don't need to reallocate and copy the data until you hit the new capacity.

I really recommend you read more about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve), especially about the difference between its *capacity* and its *size*.

Comment: Thanks. I think, I was not able to comprehend the math behind the number of calls made to ctor and dtor for each successive `push_back`.  Now it is much clearer to me as I understand the pattern behind it. :)

Answer (score 2):

The vector needs to expand to accommodate the new element. Which requires copying the existing elements into a new buffer.

If your class was `noexcept` move constructible, it would have generated calls to the move constructor instead.

The reason not every `push_back` results in the vector reallocating memory, is probably due to your standard library implementation trying to reserve some extra memory after resizing, so as to avoid having to do it too frequently. It's within the liberty of the `vector` implementation to do so, and there are several strategies for determining how much to reserve.

Comment: Why 4th push_back is having different behavior than 2nd, 3rd and 5th push_back?

Comment: Thanks. Now it is much clearer to me as I understand the maths behind it. :)

Answer (score 1):

To take a step back, there is a key requirement of [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector): elements in the vector must be stored contiguously. This means you can safely use a pointer to an element in a vector as a raw pointer to that type of element, and can therefore use array semantics and pointer arithmetic as you would expect with a fixed size array.

This also means that accessing any element of the array by its index is very fast, and takes the same amount of time regardless of the size of the array, and the index of the particular element you are accessing (this is called an O(1), or "constant time" operation).

A penalty that needs to be paid for this benefit is reallocation. When a vector is created, you typically do not know how many elements you will use, so you allocate some amount of contiguous memory to store some number of elements. If you keep adding to the vector, you will exceed this initial allocation. But you cannot just expand the amount of memory being used by your vector, because your program may have allocated the memory immediately after your current vector to some other variable. The only way to ensure the vector elements remain contiguous is to allocate a new block big enough to contain all of the elements, including the additional one, and then copy all of the elements to this new location.

As others have noted, it is quite common to grow the array size exponentially, by allocating 1.5 or 2 times the original array size, each time the capacity is exceeded. This reduces how regularly the whole array will need to be reallocated as it grows.

If instead you want a collection of elements where it is always relatively quick to append an element (or at least, always takes the same amount of time) you could use a linked list ([std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)), but then you can no longer quickly access any element by index ("random access").

Answer (score 0):

> "rather inefficient way of inserting elements into a vector"

As others have pointed out, you can prompt `std::vector` to reserve enough memory for you in the first instance to allow items to be pushed onto your vector up to this limit with having to re-allocate. If you change your code to add the following call to `reserve`:

```
vector<base> m;
m.reserve(5);
cout << "first pushback" <<endl;
```

Using `reserve` wont change the *size* of your vector but it will allocated enough memory to hold a contiguous vector of that size, thus avoiding reallocation. In your example you'll see a big reduction in the amount of copy constructors and destructors being called. If you know (roughly even) the size of your vector and construction / destruction of the type is expensive, this can make a big difference to your code.

Note that `reserve` is very different from `resize` - the first is most useful when you are pushing items onto the vector (your example), the second will create a fully populated vector of items, running the copy constructor N times; this is useful when subsequently accessing and changing items via the subscript operator.